# How to control and set the space between text lines which are soft wrapped in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to control and set the space between text lines which are soft wrapped in a flutter Text(a long string)?
I don't want to use separated lines with column or...

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
 Text("How to control and set the space between text lines which are soft wrapped in a flutter Text(a long string)? I don't want to use separated lines with column or...",
         softWrap: true,
         strutStyle: StrutStyle(height: 2),
        ),
```